# How to use HttpGet Method with two different parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I implement following method?
I have two HttpGet Methods with following parameter value:-

```
[HttpGet("{id}")] int value for route
[HttpGet("{slug}")] string value for route
```

Route looks like this on controller:-

```
[Route("api/[controller]")
```

Route configuration:-

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
   name: "defaultRoute",
   template: "{controller=Posts}/{action=GetAsync}/{id?}");
});
```

How to make sure that specific HttpGet Method gets triggered based on route value. In the above case only HttpGet with {id} route is working. Latter only works if former does not exist/remove. How can I direct my route to a method with specific header value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")
public class ValuesController : Controller {
    //GET api/values/1
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")] //int value for route
    public IActionResult GetById(int id) {
        //...
    }

    //GET api/values/something-else
    [HttpGet("{slug}")] //string value for route
    public IActionResult Get(string slug) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure routes using attributes in your controller and actions.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
      [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Index() => View();

       [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Error() => View();


       [HttpGet("[action]/{name}")]
        public IActionResult Detail(string name)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
```

You can see the two tokens `[controller]` and `[action]` indicate that we have to refer to the controller and action name that has been declared. In this case, `“Home”` is the name of the controller, and `“Detail”` the name of the action, therefore it the name of the route.